# Quando iniciar o site ja pedir o login

Tags: php, javascript, html

Estou criando um site e estou com uma dúvida. Como eu faço para quando o usuário digitar o endereço de URL ou clicar em um botão que vai para admin.html, e aparecer automaticamente a página de login? ou seja assim que iniciar o admin.html já aparecer primeiro a página do login para que depois irá abrir o admin.html

Claro se eu for pensar em fazer pelo botão eu coloco como href. Mas se quando o úsuario digitar o endereço de url, ai não vai aparecer a página de login. como poderia fazer?

meus seguintes arquivos:

login.php
conexao.php
AdminAgenda.html

login.php:

```
<?php 
include("php/conexao.php");

if(isset($_POST['email']) && strlen($_POST['email']) > 0){

    if(!isset($_SESSION))
        session_start();

    $_SESSION['email'] = $mysqli -> escape_string($_POST['email']);
    $_SESSION['senha'] = $_POST['senha'];


    $sql_code = "SELECT senha, codigo FROM usuario WHERE email = '$_SESSION[email]'";
    $sql_query = $mysqli -> query($sql_code) or die ($mysqli -> error);
    $dado = $sql_query->fetch_assoc();
    $total = $sql_query-> num_rows;


    if($total == 0){
        $erro[] = "Este email não pertence a nenhum usuário.";
    }
    else{
        if($dado['senha'] == $_SESSION['senha']){

            $_SESSION['usuario'] = $dado['codigo'];

        } else{

            $erro[] = "Senha incorreta.";
        }

    }

    if(count($erro) == 0 || !isset($erro)){
        echo "<script>alert('Login efetuado com sucesso... Seja bem vindo'); location.href='AdmAgenda.html';</script>";
    }

}


?>



<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<?php if(count($erro) > 0)
        foreach($erro as $msg){
            echo "<p>$msg</p>";
        }


    ?>

    <form method="POST" action="">
    <input value="" type="text" placeholder="email" name="email">
    <input type="password" name="senha">

        <input type="submit" value="Entrar">



    </form>


    </body>

</html>
```

AdminAgenda.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br" ng-app="AngularADM">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="author" content="Miyomic">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>Administração</title>



    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/visual.css">

    <!-- responsivo -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/bootstrap-theme.css.map" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="js/jqueryAtualizado.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jqueryAtualizado.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Fim responsivo -->

    <script src="js/digitar-home.js"></script>
    <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/teste.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="TempoHorasP1">

    <section>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <h1 class="rosa texto-centro cabeca-adm">Beleza e Harmônia</h1>
        </div>

        <div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">
            <p class="texto-centro">As configurações selecionadas abaixo sera alterada no Agendamento online. Por favor
        tomar cuidado nas escolhas das opções seguinte, suas definições são online.<br/> Em caso de congestionamento no servidor aguardar de 5 a 10 minutos.</p>

        </div>

        </div>

    </section>



    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <h2 class="rosa texto-centro margin-top30 bold">Configuração da agenda online</h2>
            <p class="rosa texto-centro margin-top20">Selecionar as horas que estão disponiveis em seu salão</p>
        </div>

        <form method="post" action="agendamento.php">
            <div class="row texto-centro">
                <div class="col-lg-12 texto-centro caixa-adm-online">

                    <div class="hora-20">
                    <span class="letra18">10:00</span>
                    <input type="checkbox"  id="blankRadio1" value="10:00" name="hora[]" aria-label="..." ng-model="um">
                    <br />
                    </div>

                    <hr class="linha-cinza" />

                    <span class="letra18">10:30</span>
                    <input type="checkbox"  id="blankRadio1" value="10:30"  name="hora[]" aria-label="..." ng-model="dois">
                    <br />
                    <hr class="linha-cinza" />

                    <span class="letra18">11:00</span>
                    <input type="checkbox"  id="blankRadio1" value="11:00" name="hora[]" aria-label="..." ng-model="tres">
                    <br />
                    <hr class="linha-cinza" />

                    <span class="letra18">11:30</span>
                    <input type="checkbox"  id="blankRadio1" value="11:30" name="hora[]" aria-label="..." ng-model="quatro">
                    <br />
                    <hr class="linha-cinza" />

                    <span class="letra18">13:00</span>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="hora[]" id="blankRadio1" value="13:00" aria-label="..." ng-model="cinco">
                    <br />
                    <hr class="linha-cinza" />

                    <span class="letra18">13:30</span>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="hora[]" id="blankRadio1" value="13:30" aria-label="..." ng-model="seis">
                    <br />
                    <hr class="linha-cinza" />

                    <span class="letra18">14:00</span>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="hora[]" id="blankRadio1" value="14:00" aria-label="..." ng-model="sete">
                    <br />
                    <hr class="linha-cinza" />

                    <span class="letra18">14:30</span>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="hora[]" id="blankRadio1" value="14:30" aria-label="..." ng-model="oito">
                    <br />
                    <hr class="linha-cinza" />

                    <span class="letra18">15:00</span>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="hora[]" id="blankRadio1" value="15:00" aria-label="..." ng-model="dez">
                    <br />
                    <hr class="linha-cinza" />

                    <span class="letra18">15:30</span>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="hora[]" id="blankRadio1" value="15:30" aria-label="..." ng-model="onze">
                    <br />
                    <hr class="linha-cinza" />

                    <span class="letra18">16:00</span>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="hora[]" id="blankRadio1" value="16:00" aria-label="..." ng-model="doze">
                    <br />
                    <hr class="linha-cinza" />

                    <span class="letra18">16:30</span>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="hora[]" id="blankRadio1" value="16:30" aria-label="..." ng-model="treze">
                    <br />
                    <hr class="linha-cinza" />


                    <div class="hora-20">
                    <span class="letra18">17:00</span>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="hora[]" id="blankRadio1" value="17:00" aria-label="..." ng-model="quatorze">
                    <br />
                        </div>

                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row texto-centro margin-top20">
                <button ng-click="atualizar()" value="descobrir" class="botao-atualizar">Atualizar <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-send branco"></span></button>

            </div>
        </form>
    </div>



</body>

</html>
```

Creio que deve ser por javascript ou estou enganado? alguém poderia me ajudar? 
Obrigado...

Comment: Quando o usuário estiver logado ele entra na admin e quando ele não estiver ele é redirecionado para o login é isso?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pegando a ideia do amigo LocalHost eu faria um include/require de um arquivo php que validasse se o usuário esta logado ou nao no seu sistema, isso porque já pensando a longo prazo e no crescimento do seu sistema.

Isso é valido pois se seu sistema crescer voce vai sempre chamar o mesmo arquivo de validação e se precisar mudar algo a manutenção vai ser mais rapida e simples que alterar a validacao arquivos por arquivos.

No seu index.php ficaria assim:

```
<?php require_once 'valida.php';?>// AQUI chama o arquivo de validacao

<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="pt-br" ng-app="AngularADM">

    <head>

// Restante do codigo HTML
```

E no seu arquivo de validação, no qual chamamos aqui de *valida.php* você coloca o script de validação:

```
<?php 
 //verifica se o usuário não esta logado
 if(!isset($_SESSION['usuario']) || empty($_SESSION['usuario']){
     header('location:login.php');
  }else{
     header('location:AdmimAgenda.php');
  }
 ?>
```

Dessa forma voce pode mudar a forma de validação sempre que precisar e de forma rápida, alterando apenas um arquivo, bem como poderá direcionar o usuário a pagina que quiser caso já tenha uma sessão valida.

Agora em cada pagina que precisa ser validada, é so fazer o include/require do arquivo valida.php

Comment: Só que eu estou com um problema... quando eu faço o login ele me mostra a mensagem que deu login efetuado com sucesso mas carrega a pagina e volta para a pagina de login, o que seria isso?

Comment: veja se voce esta gravando a sessão no momento do login, senao vai acontecer de seu arquivo chamar o arquivo valida.php e nao encontrar a sessão, ai então ele vai voltar novamente pra pagina de login

Comment: ele me aparece esse erro `Undefined variable: erro in C:\nome_pasta\login.php on line 34` e nessa linha 34 é essa linha de código `if(count($erro) == 0 || !isset($erro)){
        echo "<script>alert('Seja bem vindo!'); location.href='admagenda.php';</script>";
    }`  verifiquei e tinha dado com o nome errado, concertei mas mesmo assim da esse erro...

Comment: mude a condicao do seu if, primeiro coloque o isset na verificacao depois o count

Comment: mudou nada... coloquei no local do direcionamento o link desse forúm e funcionou agora quando eu coloco **admagenda.php** ele volta para a página do login... creio que ele esta em um tipo de loop...

Comment: cara, atualize seus script da forma correta que voce esta usando. Esse loop é bem provavel que esteja acontecendo pelo seu arquivo de validacao estar tentando validar a sessão e ela nao deve estar setada

Comment: Nao esqueca do session_start() para validar as sessoes

Comment: Ok... obrigado...

Answer (score 3):

Bom, se eu entendi bem, você terá que colocar nas primeiras linhas do código, que precisa do login, a instrução requerindo o login, e para isso ele precisa ser `.php`.

Entao o primeiro passo é salvar o seu `AdmimAgenda.html` como  `AdmimAgenda.php`. E depois inserir logo antes do cabeçalho da sua pagina a verificação se o usuario esta logado.
Ai o AdmimAgenda.php ficara mais ou menos assim:

```
<?php 
 //verifica se o usuário esta não logado
 if(!isset($_SESSION['usuario']) || empty($_SESSION['usuario']){
 // caso ele não estiver logado, exibe o link para redirecionar para o login
    echo "<a href='login.php'> Faça o login para continuar</a>";
 // e cancela o carregamento do resto da pagina...
  return;
  }
 ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br" ng-app="AngularADM">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="author" content="Miyomic">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>Administração</title>



    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/visual.css">

    <!-- responsivo -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/bootstrap-theme.css.map" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="js/jqueryAtualizado.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jqueryAtualizado.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Fim responsivo -->

    <script src="js/digitar-home.js"></script>
    <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/teste.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="TempoHorasP1">

    <section>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <h1 class="rosa texto-centro cabeca-adm">Beleza e Harmônia</h1>
        </div>

        <div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">
            <p class="texto-centro">As configurações selecionadas abaixo sera alterada no Agendamento online. Por favor
        tomar cuidado nas escolhas das opções seguinte, suas definições são online.<br/> Em caso de congestionamento no servidor aguardar de 5 a 10 minutos.</p>

        </div>

        </div>

    </section>



    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <h2 class="rosa texto-centro margin-top30 bold">Configuração da agenda online</h2>
            <p class="rosa texto-centro margin-top20">Selecionar as horas que estão disponiveis em seu salão</p>
        </div>

        <form method="post" action="agendamento.php">
            <div class="row texto-centro">
                <div class="col-lg-12 texto-centro caixa-adm-online">

                    <div class="hora-20">
                    <span class="letra18">10:00</span>
                    <input type="checkbox"  id="blankRadio1" value="10:00" name="hora[]" aria-label="..." ng-model="um">
                    <br />
                    </div>

                    <hr class="linha-cinza" />

                    <span class="letra18">10:30</span>
                    <input type="checkbox"  id="blankRadio1" value="10:30"  name="hora[]" aria-label="..." ng-model="dois">
                    <br />
                    <hr class="linha-cinza" />

                    <span class="letra18">11:00</span>
                    <input type="checkbox"  id="blankRadio1" value="11:00" name="hora[]" aria-label="..." ng-model="tres">
                    <br />
                    <hr class="linha-cinza" />

                    <span class="letra18">11:30</span>
                    <input type="checkbox"  id="blankRadio1" value="11:30" name="hora[]" aria-label="..." ng-model="quatro">
                    <br />
                    <hr class="linha-cinza" />

                    <span class="letra18">13:00</span>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="hora[]" id="blankRadio1" value="13:00" aria-label="..." ng-model="cinco">
                    <br />
                    <hr class="linha-cinza" />

                    <span class="letra18">13:30</span>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="hora[]" id="blankRadio1" value="13:30" aria-label="..." ng-model="seis">
                    <br />
                    <hr class="linha-cinza" />

                    <span class="letra18">14:00</span>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="hora[]" id="blankRadio1" value="14:00" aria-label="..." ng-model="sete">
                    <br />
                    <hr class="linha-cinza" />

                    <span class="letra18">14:30</span>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="hora[]" id="blankRadio1" value="14:30" aria-label="..." ng-model="oito">
                    <br />
                    <hr class="linha-cinza" />

                    <span class="letra18">15:00</span>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="hora[]" id="blankRadio1" value="15:00" aria-label="..." ng-model="dez">
                    <br />
                    <hr class="linha-cinza" />

                    <span class="letra18">15:30</span>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="hora[]" id="blankRadio1" value="15:30" aria-label="..." ng-model="onze">
                    <br />
                    <hr class="linha-cinza" />

                    <span class="letra18">16:00</span>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="hora[]" id="blankRadio1" value="16:00" aria-label="..." ng-model="doze">
                    <br />
                    <hr class="linha-cinza" />

                    <span class="letra18">16:30</span>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="hora[]" id="blankRadio1" value="16:30" aria-label="..." ng-model="treze">
                    <br />
                    <hr class="linha-cinza" />


                    <div class="hora-20">
                    <span class="letra18">17:00</span>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="hora[]" id="blankRadio1" value="17:00" aria-label="..." ng-model="quatorze">
                    <br />
                        </div>

                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row texto-centro margin-top20">
                <button ng-click="atualizar()" value="descobrir" class="botao-atualizar">Atualizar <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-send branco"></span></button>

            </div>
        </form>
    </div>



</body>

</html>
```

Espero ter ajudado, se não for o que quer comente ai!!